# Can forward and backward selection give the same model?

Tags: r, subset

I'm using forward stepwise selection and backward stepwise selection to produce models in R. However, I got the exactly same model for two different methods. Is that normal?

```
##Forward selection
library(MASS)
min.model <- lm(BY2XMSTD ~ 1, data = NESL88_c)
max.model <- lm(BY2XMSTD ~ ., data = NESL88_c)
scp <- list(lower = min.model, upper = max.model)
fwd <- stepAIC(min.model, 
           direction = 'forward', 
           scope = scp)
fwd$coefficients

## Backward selection
library(MASS)
min.model <- lm(BY2XMSTD ~ 1, data = NESL88_c)
max.model <- lm(BY2XMSTD ~ ., data = NESL88_c)
scp <- list(lower = min.model, upper = max.model)
bwd <- stepAIC(max.model, 
           direction = 'backward', 
           scope = scp)
bwd$coefficients
```

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be more about statistics. it could happen, sure, you should not expect it to. please make a reproducible example. I used your code with the `mtcars` data set, and it did not give me the same model. you could have tested this on another data set or even a subset of what you have to see if it happens in other situations

Comment: Either case is possible. You could get the same final model or they can be rather different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general, forward and backward step wise regression can give you the same result, but there is not a requirement that such a result be the case. Even if you have the same number of terms in the final model, forward and backward can give you a different model. It's all a matter of the statistic (often an F statistic) used in the step wise process.